# Alternatives to JMS for queuing

Tags: queue, jms

We have a REST web service that receives requests from external systems and makes updates to our DB accordingly. I'm looking to implement a caching/queuing solution for the requests that come in, as we've had some DB server challenges lately, and have lost some messages when the DB server went down.

Before I start putting together a simple persistent file-based queue, I'm wanting to see if there are any good alternatives to JMS as it's use is restricted in our environment.

Current platforms:
Jboss 4.3
Richfaces 3.3
Spring 3.0.5
RESTEasy

** UPDATES **

Per skaffman's question below, my requirements for clustering, transactions, etc.

- Clustering: Our web and app servers are all clustered, so the queue(s) will need to be able to process items from all cluster nodes.  However, our commits are essentially atomic, so ordering and synchronization issues are extremely minimal.  Thread and cluster-safety is not really a factor.  Separate/Independent queues on each cluster would be sufficient.
- Transactions:  Again, due to the atomic nature of our data, transactional needs are minmal/not required outside of each individual request.
- Security:  Moderate concern, but I would anticipate that to be handled by our regular security on the Web Service.  I wouldn't anticipate anything reading or writing to the queue(s) other than the web-app itself.  That would only be necessary in instances of high volume or when the DB is unavailable.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: What are your requirements regarding transations, clustering and security?

Comment: @anubhava - Good question.  I'm trying to find out the details, but the general word is that it's forbidden/restricted within our tech stack and won't be allowed in the web environment with no exceptions.

Comment: All the alternatives of JMS (ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ etc) don't provide persistence therefore I can't think of any other JMS alternative to meet your requirements sans building your own custom solution. And even if you find one what are the chances that your organizational restrictions will allow that?

Answer (score 0):

For one project we did use a queue (HornetQ) but was integrated in the war and deployable on a Tomcat because the customer did not want Weblogic or JBoss application servers,  but if your restricting policy goes to your application architecture as well such solution would be forbidden.

For another project we did not use any JMS implementation and we make the asynchronous implementation by using a message database and the [Service Activator](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#overview-endpoints-service-activator) of the [spring-integration framework](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration) for consuming the events. 
That way any message publisher just insert a row in a DB table and the Service Activator trigs the event and call any other service (Spring, Web-service, etc...).